# How do I reference a foreign key to serial datatype

Tags: mysql

I tried to create the following tables in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cliente(
    id_cliente SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_cliente VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    direccion_cliente VARCHAR(40)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS archivo(
    id_archivo SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_archivo VARCHAR(30),
    id_cliente INTEGER
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fecha(
    id_fecha INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    fk_cliente INTEGER,
    id_archivo INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(fk_cliente) REFERENCES cliente(id_cliente)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

But, I get the error:

```
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'adm_bordados.fecha' (errno: 150)
```

The last table `fetcha` is not created.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both columns of the foreign key must be of the same type. Since `SERIAL` is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE` (according to the [MySQL Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html)), you will have to change the type of `fecha.fk_cliente`. Changing the last statement to this should do it for you:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fecha(
    id_fecha INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    fk_cliente BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    id_archivo INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(fk_cliente) REFERENCES cliente(id_cliente)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```